# Passing additional information through controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a comment model and when a comment is created it makes a note of the profile_name of the user and saves it. So it is basically saving @user.profile_name as comment.profile_name.

If I now want to show additional information from the user who has that profile_name such as @user.avatar - how would I query it without having to add extra fields to be saved when a comment is created?

I Imagined I could do something like

```
@user = User.all
@comment_user = User.where(:profile_name => @user.profile_name)
```

And then run

```
<% @comment_user.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.first_name %>
<% end %>
```

In the view but I get an error

```
undefined method `profile_name' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x007fc2081c7290>
```

I'm not even sure if that is the correct way to proceed even if I didn't get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to call `profile_name` on `User.all`, but what you want is a single user.  Try:

```
@user = User.first
@comment_user = User.where(:profile_name => @user.profile_name)
```

That being said, you should be using ActiveRecord associations instead. Instead of storing the user's profile_name in the comment record, you should store the user_id .  Create a `belongs_to :user` association in the Comment model and then you can access the other user attributes directly.

First add a :user_id integer column to the the comments table, and then define your associations:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

When creating a new comment, you can do something like:

```
@comment = @user.comments.create(text: 'my awesome comment')
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= @comment.text %>
<%= @comment.user.profile_name %>
```